# How to create an instance of value types using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, value-type

I want to create an instance of value types like <s>`System.String`</s>, `System.Boolean`, `System.Int32`, etc. I get qualified names of types like <s>`System.String` or</s> `MyNamespace.Employee` and I have to create an instance and return back. I use `Activator.CreateInstance` and `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` to create instances. But it fails in case of value types. I cannot hard code the logic in case of value types. I need a generic way of creating instances of both value types and reference types.

Comment: System.String is reference type, not a value type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What exactly is it you are trying to do? `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` is used mainly by serialization code; outside of that you shouldn't really use it. It *sounds* like you might just need something like `TypeConverter`, i.e. (for these types)

```
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(someType);
object obj = tc.ConvertFromString(s);
```

Comment: Oh, lovely for generic stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

What exactly is failing?  I tried the following code to see if there is a problem with value types:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Int32));
```

It gives me an Int32 instance set to 0.

Where exactly is your code failing?  Otherwise I would say the problem lies with the way you are loading the type, not the way you are creating the instance.

Comment: Eish Jaco!  I just went back to change my 'var' to an 'int', in case 'var' was unfamiliar to the OP, and you sneak in the exact same line of code as me. :-)

Comment: Haha - you gotta be quick on the draw :-)

Answer (score 1):

For BCL Value Types (and when using Strings to describe types) ensure you are not using C# keywords and ensure the Type is fully qualified with namespace. For example, C# int is successfully created this way with Activator.CreateInstance(..)

```
    object num = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
```

You will get failed attempts if you try to use language-specific aliases like `"int"` or short forms like `"Int32"`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
int x = (int)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (Int32), true);
```